# Hibernate method to only return records where the value in a specify column has changed

Tags: java, sql, database, hibernate, criteria

Table: `Profile`

```
pk   fk fname lname  dob         ssn        createDate  ModifyDate
1    22 bob   smith  01/02/1978  123456789  01/27/2012  null
2    22 bob   smith  01/02/1978  987654321  01/27/2012  01/28/2012
3    22 bob   smith  04/02/1944  123456789  01/27/2012  01/29/2012
4    22 bob   dole   04/02/1944  123456789  01/27/2012  01/30/2012
5    22 bob   dole   02/12/1913  123456789  01/27/2012  01/31/2012
6    22 john  dole   02/12/1913  123456789  01/27/2012  02/02/2012
7    22 bob   dole   11/22/1994  123456789  01/27/2012  02/03/2012
```

I would like to return the last three times dob was changed for `fk = 22`.

So that will return record 7, 6, 4.

So I can do something like this:

```
Integer foreignKey = new Integer(22);
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Profile.class);
List results = criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("fk",foreignKey))
  .addOrder( Order.desc("ModifyDate") ).list();
```

Now I know I could write a for loop and compare the dob to see which dates have changed.

But is there a hibernate method or easier way to do this?

How about if i wanted to see if both `dob` and `fname` change?

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please don't just dump console output here. Try to format your tables so the display nicely.

Comment: How do you know that `dob` was *changed*?

Comment: @Tichodroma I actually typed this up in wordpad and then tried using html <table> but it didn't work. So i will try to format it better next time. Thanks for the welcome.

Comment: You can just indent everything that is some kind of code by for spaces. No need for HTML markup.

Comment: @Tichodroma I guess that's the question. Some background. There's a profile table and whenever any attribute in the table changes a trigger creates a history record in another table. So above is the history table. I only need to retrieve the last three times the dob was changed. So I think the only way to do that is to compare every record dob attribute and see if there's a change. So I'm asking is there an easier way? Some hibernate property I can set or method I could use?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [Hibernate Envers](http://www.jboss.org/envers), but I don't think you can automate this kind of queries with it. Afaik you only have two possibilities to achieve this:

1. Create an appropriate query (Criteria, HQL, SQL) to retrieve the according records or load the whole history and identify the records in your Java code.
2. Extend your history table and trigger (or hibernate event listener) to include the names of the changed properties/columns. Maybe with an additional boolean column per property/column. This way you can query the according records quite efficiently.